# UISegmentedControl looks strange in iOS 6 and SDK 7

Tags: ios6, xcode5, uisegmentedcontrol

After migrating my project to Xcode 5 / SDK 7 the `UISegmentedControl` looks very strange on my old `iOS 6` iPad.

The font is bold, bigger and the segment has a blue background. (It's like setting the style to plain)
[image: Plain]

But I want it like the bar style:
[image: Bar]

The `UISegmentedControl` is part of a navigation bar.

How can I change this?

Answer (score 0):

It only happens if you're working with `Xamarin.iOS` and the new SDK 7 (Xcode 5). I'm not sure wether the Interface Builder creates other XML code for the storyboard or `Xamarin.iOS` is parsing something wrong.

The workaround is to set in your `UIViewController` in the method `ViewDidLoad()` the style to 'bar style' in code. Then it looks on a iPad with iOS 6 like before ;)